# How to fix error of a button trying to delete an item form a list?

Tags: swift, list, mvvm, swiftui

Im making a practice app where the main view is a list with a button at the bottom. Pressing the button adds an item to the list. When the item is tapped, it presents the detail view that has a button at the middle of the view.

What Im trying to do is that when the button is pressed, it deletes the item form the list and move me back to the main view. My problem is that I got an error when implementing the delete function to the button.

The error is this one: Cannot convert value of type '(IndexSet) -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'

How can I fix it?

This is the main view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: CPStore
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<store.items.count, id:\.self) { index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Detail(index: index)) {
                            VStack {
                                Text(self.store.items[index].title)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.add()
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                        .frame(width: 87, height: 87)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Practice")
        }
    }
    
    func add() {
        withAnimation {
            store.items.append(CPModel(title: "Item \(store.items.count + 1)"))
        }
    }
}
```

This is the detail view:

```
struct Detail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: CPStore
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: removeRecording) { // <- I got the error here
            Image(systemName: "trash")
        }
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .font(.system(size: 24))
    }
    
    func removeRecording(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            store.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

The model:

```
struct CPModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
class CPStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [CPModel]()
}
```

Comment: I think you need to pass the IndexSet parameter to removeRecoding function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572822/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-the-action-of-button-with-swiftui)

update your removeRecording function

```
func removeRecording(at offsets: IndexSet) -> () -> () {
        return {
            withAnimation {
                store.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
```

and change your button to pass the parameter

```
Button(action: removeRecording(at: [index]))
```